# Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: 'Unexpected character encountered while parsing value:

Tags: c#, json, deserialization

I have a JSON file like below

```json
{
    "Valid": true
}
```

And the following model

```cs
public class Account
{
    public bool Valid { get; set; }
    public Account()
    {
        Valid = true;
    }
}
```

When running the following code to deserialize

```cs
public static void JsonDeserializeTest(Type datatype, string filePath)
{
    Account account = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Account>(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string>(File.ReadAllText(filePath)));
}
```

I'm receiving the following error:

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: 'Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: {. Path '', line 1, position 1.'

Comment: `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string>(` ? why are you trying to decode json twice? Does the file contain a json string literal like `"this is a string"`?

Answer (score 3):

You have to write your code just like this:

```
public static void JsonDeserializeTest(Type datatype, string filePath)

 {

    Account account = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Account> 
                                 (File.ReadAllText(filePath));
}
```

Comment: Yes it is worked. also i tried by modifying JSON file like this




"{
'Valid': true
}"